# Get data from php file + ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, curl

i want to get data that's loaded in my PHP file in javascript.
This is what I do:

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
    // GET VALUE OF APPID
    var appid = $("#appid").val()
    // GET JSON FROM PHP SCRIPT
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '../loadjson.php',
        data: {
            'appid': appid
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function(jqXHR,error, errorThrown) {  
            if(jqXHR.status&&jqXHR.status==400){
                alert(jqXHR.responseText); 
            }else{
                alert("Something went wrong");
            }
        }
    });

});
```

When I click a button I get the value of a textbox and call ajax function.
my javascript file is located in root/js/file.js and my php file in root/loadjson.php

My PHP file:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['appid']) && !empty($_POST['appid'])) {
    $appid = $_POST['appid'];
}
$json_url  ='http://api.url.com/api/gateway/call/1.4/getApp?appid=' . $appid;

$ch = curl_init($json_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$str = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$data = json_decode($str);

$array = $data;
$object = $array->app[0]; 

echo $object;
```

?>

The problem is I get always an alert box with "Something went wrong" but I can't find the solution. Does someone see my fault?

I get this:
[image]

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wKe2U/

Comment: Try alerting something useful like `alert(thrownError);`.

Comment: I have done that but it doesn't show anything. Just an empty alert box ...

Comment: Help me understand what do you need `$array = $data;` for?

Comment: @Rikesh Well we know it isn't an 400 error, can you use developer tools in your browser to see the request and response?

Comment: Please provide a url or jsFiddle.

Comment: Also you might want to json_encode() the returned data, as I am guessing it is either a php object or XML and it expects a JSON return

Comment: ^ or a valid App ID so we can test. Also follow @We0 's suggestion and check the response using firebug or other developer tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You are not preventing your form submission, you are using form and
>   input button submit type. So, while you clicking on that button your
>   form being submit. So, first you stop your form submission in your
>   ajax code.
>
> Second thing is that you are using method get in your ajax code and
>   trying to get values by 'POST' in your php code. So, kindly use $_GET
>   or change ajax code type: 'POST'
>
> Third thing is that your url is invalid you should use
>   url:'loadjson.php'

here I am sharing code:

```
//Ajax code
$(function () {
    $("#submit").click(function (e) {
        // stop form submission first
        e.preventDefault();
        // GET VALUE OF APPID
        var appid = $("#appid").val()
            // GET JSON FROM PHP SCRIPT
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : 'loadjson.php',
                data: {'appid':appid},
                success : function (d) {
                    alert(d);
                },
                error : errorHandler
            });
    });
});

function errorHandler(jqXHR, exception) {
    if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
        alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
    } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
        alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
    } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
        alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
    } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
        alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
    } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
        alert('Time out error.');
    } else if (exception === 'abort') {
        alert('Ajax request aborted.');
    } else {
        alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
    }
}
```

Hope, you understand where you were wrong  :)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure but in your js code I see

```
 type: 'GET',
```

but in your php code use POST method to load value

```
if(isset($_POST['appid']) && !empty($_POST['appid'])) {
    $appid = $_POST['appid'];
}
```

Comment: I wan't to get back a json but depending the value i sent.

Comment: why you don't use get method in your php?

Comment: Problem is in your php script. Try print variables which you use in php code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give

url: 'loadjson.php'

in your js file

Answer (score 0):

You are issuing a `GET` ajax request, and you are relying on `$_POST` information in your script, just use `$_GET`.

You are getting a notice for undefined var `$appid`, click on the red row in your devtools to see the response you are getting, and associated error code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '../loadjson.php',
        datatype: 'json' ,
        data: {
            'appid': appid
        },
...
```